# "English learner" vs "math learner"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases, nouns

ChatGPT rewrote my expression "English leaners with Chinese as native language" to "Chinese learners of English", and I don't know if it is right. What I want to mean is "English language learners with Chinese as their native language". I know by English language learners we mean those who are learning English as a target language.

My questions are the following two:

1. "English learners" and "English language learners" are different, right? But what is a math learner?
2. "English learners of Chinese" means those English people who are learning Chinese language, right? Is it idiomatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version is something of a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) because starting with *English learners* makes the reader think you are talking about English people (not British - England is only a part of Great Britain) who are learning something. The phrase *English learner* on its own is ambiguous; it could mean either a person learning English or an English person learning.

Comment: I'd be quite surprtised if you could find *any* bona fide references to the collocation "English learners" where "English" refers to the learners' *native nationality*, rather than the *language* being learned. It's so likely to be misunderstood I'd expect ***learners** [of anything, but probably **not** the English language] **who are / speak English / are Anglophones*** or similar, if that was the intended meaning.

Comment: I can get Google hits for "English learners of Chinese" where "English learners" refers to people who have English as nationality or native tongue. There are contexts where "English learners" would refer to English people, but without an context you would respect it meant the other thing.

Comment: Is "Chinese learners of English" idiomatic?

Answer (score -1):

1.) "English learners" and "English language learners" *can* be different, but they don't have to.

"English learners" refers to learners who in some form have the attribute "English". That could be that they are learning the English language. But that could also be that they are learners who have the English nationality and are learning, for example, figure skating. Which of the two, or any number of other possibilities, actually is the case is not contained in the two words "English learners". That has be derived from the context.

Similarly, "English language learners" refers to learners for whom in some form the English language plays a role. The most common interpretation would probably be that the learners are learning the English language. It could also be understood as the learners are being taught using the English language, and are learning some other subject. Again, the detailed meaning needs to be derived from the context.

2.) "English learners of Chinese" *can* refer to British people who are learning Chinese, that's correct. But there's some ambiguity here as well. If the reader assumes that "Chinese" refers to the Chinese language (and not, for example, to Chinese cooking), they would probably assume that "English" refers to a language as well, being the English language. And English isn't only the native language for British people, but also for people from the USA, Australia, New Zealand and other countries. (And the notion that every single British person, American person, Australian person and so forth considers English their native language is simplified as well.) So, an "English learner of Chinese" can for example mean somebody in Sidney learning the Chinese language.

Regarding "English" and "British", on the British Isles there are multiple nations, namely England, Wales, Scotland and Ireland. Those four had a complex history with each other over the centuries. And with that, I haven't talked about the [British Oversea Territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories) or the [Crown Dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Dependencies), who are "British" as well. So technically, "English" and "British" isn't the same. But in everyday language, the distinction isn't always made correctly.